# Joining two tables for the result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in a database `person` and `order` tables.

PERSON table:

```
PERSON_ID | NAME
```

ORDER table:

```
ORDER_ID | ORDER_NO | PERSON_ID
```

I need to display all the orders + a name of corresponding person if it exists, if not just order details.

So far I got up to query:

```
SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_NO, order.PERSON_ID, NAME 
  FROM person, order 
 WHERE person.PERSON_ID = order.PERSON_ID AND 
       person.FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

Which gives me orders only if the name is available whereas I need to display all the orders despite the fact if name is available or not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `order` is a reserved word in SQL. Try to avoid it as an identifier.

Comment: @wildplasser Alternatively, escape *all* identifiers, in case some future DBMS introduces "person" (for example) as a keyword. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `LEFT JOIN` for that:

```
   SELECT o.order_id, o.order_no, o.person_id, p.name
     FROM `order` o
LEFT JOIN person p
       ON p.person_id = o.person_id AND p.FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL
```

With `LEFT JOIN` if the `name` is `null` it will still give you the orders.

Comment: +1 I posted a `RIGHT JOIN` answer but my `p.first_name IS NOT NULL` broke it. So... I, for one, welcome our new `LEFT JOIN` overlords.